# Jquery and AJAX is not working properly in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to delete the record asynchronously without refreshing the page but after clicking on destroy link the events get deleted asynchronously but the problem is it is still displaying on the screen unless we refresh the page. I don't know why it is happening. Any help will be appreciable.

Controller Code :

```
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

View Code :

```
    <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td><%= event.date %></td>
        <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.address %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

destroy.js.erb code :

```
$('#edit_event_<%=@event.id%>').remove();
```

application.js code :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit  Didn't understand what you want to say. Actually i want to delete the record asynchronously without refreshing the page.

Comment: I overlooked.. sorry

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of what you want to delete?

Comment: @MurifoX I have added the view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you perform the `DELETE` action, and you tried to remove the line in the `destroy.js.erb` callback. The problem is that there is no `DOM` element in your table with the id of `#edit_event_<%=@event.id%>`. All you need to do is change the `<tr>` to:

```
<tr id="edit_event_<%=@event.id%>">
```

So, when the `destroy.js.erb` is triggered, it will know that to do.